# Hosting 2 WordPress websites in /public_html/ & /public_html/subdirectory/ at the same time

Tags: multisite, htaccess

Previously, we had a subdomain multisite in `/public_html/`:

- `www.example.com` (primary site)
- `site1.example.com`
- `site2.example.com`

plus another subdirectory multisite in `/site3.example.com/`

- `site3.example.com` (primary site)
- `site3.example.com/subsite4`

It got decided that we'd use subdirectories across the board. So now we have

- `www.example.com` (primary site)
- `www.example.com/site1`
- `www.example.com/site2`

All of these work fine.

However

- `www.example.com/site3` &
- `www.example.com/site3/subsite4`

display a 500 internal server error - too many redirects.

I've updated `www.example.com/site3`'s `wp-config.php` to ensure:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.example.com/site3');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

Its `.htaccess` is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site3/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . /site3/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've updated the tables:

- `wp_2_options`
- `wp_blogs`
- `wp_options`

with the new URLs: `www.example.com/site3`

The `.htaccess` in `/public_html/` is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The `/public_html/wp-config.php` contains:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.example.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
```

Is the site in `/public_html` causing the site in `/public_html/site3` problems?

How would I resolve this, please?

Help appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused by your setup. Is site3 a multisite install or not? If these sites were on a multisite then there wouldn't be a site3 folder with a wp-config.php file. That's just a separate install entirely.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, yes, site3 is a subdirectory multisite. I've moved `site3.example.com` to `www.example.com/site3`

Comment: "site3 is a subdirectory multisite" - so you have a subdirectory multisite _within_ a subdirectory multisite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was caused by:

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.example.com/site3');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
```

Changing this to:

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.example.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/site3/');
```

with a similar change in the `wp_blogs` table solved the problem.

Comment: Presumably this is how `/site1` and `/site2` were already configured?